# Labelling script block in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I know there is a way to label individual sh commands like such in declarative Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('foo'){
    steps {
        sh script:"echo 'do something...'", label:"bar"
    }
}
```

However, is there a way to label script blocks like this:

```
stage('foo'){
    steps {
        script {
            try {
                echo 'Trying something...'
            } catch (Exception e) {
                echo 'Trying something else...'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without labeling each and every sh commands like this:

```
stage('foo'){
    steps {
        script {
            try {
                sh script:"echo 'Trying something...'", label:"bar"
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sh script:"echo 'Trying something else...'", label:"bar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `label` key belongs to the [workflow durable task step](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-durable-task-step-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/durable_task/DurableTaskStep.java#L108) plugin. While `script` block belongs to [workflow model definition](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/master/pipeline-model-definition/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/steps/ScriptStep.java) plugin, that doesn't implement any `label`. So, there is no way to label a script block

Comment: So I should label every step one by one?